# Fooling with the for iterator

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

The following piece of code is from a program which I reviewed. It calculates the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
for i in 2..input.to_i
  fibonacci = a + b
  a = b
  b = fibonacci
  i += 1            # <-  This
end
```

The commented line `i += 1` actually does nothing.

Is it correct to say that `i` is a block parameter? I.e. is the `for` statement functionally the same as `(2..input.to_i).each do |i|`?

The line `i += 1` actually doesn't affect the iterator. Is it possible for the iterator to move to a certain iteration, using the `for`, `each` or `times` loops?

Any reference to how these iterators work would be also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, here are your desired references:

- [`for` loop syntax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop)
- [`next` statment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-next+Statement)
- [`redo` statment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-redo+Statement)
- [`Enumerator` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html)

To answer your questions:

1. **Is it correct to say that i is a block parameter?**

   No. `for` does not introduce a new variable scope or uses a block.
2. **Is the `for` statement functionally the same as `(2..input.to_i).each do |i|`?**

   No. `for i in ...` creates a variable `i` in the scope where `for` was executed, while `each` won't do that (IIRC earlier Ruby versions did this).
3. **Is it possible for the iterator to move to a certain iteration?**

   You can skip or redo single iterations like so (possible in `each` iterations, too):

   ```
   wait_until = Time.now + 10
   for i in [1,2,3]
     redo if Time.now < wait_until # actively sleep
     next if i.even?
   end
   ```

   But you can't jump to arbritary positions.

   To get a better control over your iteration, you'll need an `Enumerator` instance. If you call `each` without arguments/block, you will get an enumerator:

   ```
   enum = [1,2,3].each
   begin
     while i = enum.next
       puts i
     end
   rescue StopIteration
   end

   # equivalent to
   # [1,2,3].each {|i| puts i }
   ```

   `enum` now responds to things like `rewind`, `peek`, etc. (see docs linked above).

Comment: I think your second point is slightly misleading. Yes, strictly speaking, it is not exactly the same, because variable scope is different. However, section 11.5.2.3.4 of the ISO Ruby Language Specification says that `for var1, var2 in expression; do_something end` is *indeed* evaluated as `expression.each do |var1, var2| do_something end` except that the block doesn't have its own scope. So, scope is the *only* difference, otherwise it is, in fact, just a purely local syntactic translation (i.e. syntactic sugar) for `each`.

Comment: You are indeed correct, let me reword that point when I have some free time later...

Answer (score 3):

`for` is indeed mostly just sugar for `each` (Try using `for` on a non enumerable object - it should complain about it not responding to each). It differs in that it doesn't create block scope.

How `each` is implemented depends on the object you are calling it on (each is the method on which all of Enumerable is built). In any case the block will be called with a succession of values. Reassigning the block variable that is yielded does nothing - upon the next iteration `i` is set to whatever the next value should be.

You can skip with `next` or terminate with `break` but that's it as far as controlling the iteration goes - there's no way of saying "jump forwards 3"